# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'addData'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

This type of error is showing when I call the ajax in aspx form to the code method.

This type of error questions is asked many times in stackoverflow as well as other sites also but their solution is not worked for me.

Thats why I asked duplicate type of question.

Full error is like this,

**{Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'addData'.",…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'addData'."
StackTrace: "   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
?   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
?   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
?   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"**

Here is my ajax code from where I call the cs method,

```
var addData = {
    'name': document.getElementById("txt_unitname").value,
    'isactive': document.getElementById("chb_isactive").value
};

function AddUnit() {

        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "UnitMaster.aspx/AddUnit",
            data: JSON.stringify(addData),                    
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to do this operation.');

            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the cs method from where the ajax call want to work,

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string AddUnit(string addData)
{

    return addData;
}
```

Hence, when I call the ajax at that time only it shows the error and therefore, webmethod cant be call. I check by put the debug point.

Comment: Honestly, you would be better off utilizing a generic handler file.  It would separate the code, also will allow you to access the data directly from the `HttpContext`.  Also, your issue is how you are formatting your `addData` in the Ajax.  Your variables should be wrapped in single quote to form a valid Json Object and you need to define the `addData` in the `data` portion of Ajax.  To avoid those errors a function should be used to create a valid JavaScript object that is converted into a Json Object via the `JSON.stringify(...)` call.

Comment: data : { addData: JSON.stringify(addData) }